# Don't show label tooltip in Chart.js if hover is less than 1 second

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have some information inside the doughnut chart and want to prevent tooltip blinks when this info is accessed with the mouse.

Check out the attached screenshot below:

[image]

I am trying to implement the following solution:

- Not show the label tooltip if the label hover is less than 1 second.
- If the label hover is more than 1 second (i.e. the cursor is stuck on the label for some time) then I need to show the tooltip.

Check out the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ev2tnsb/)

```js
var chart_data = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

```js
function chart() {
 
  var options = {
  
    type: 'doughnut',
   
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: chart_data,
          backgroundColor: [ "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange" ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
       cutoutPercentage : 65,
       responsive: false,
       
       tooltips: {
          callbacks: { label: label_tooltip }
        },
    }
  }
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-container').getContext('2d')
  
  new Chart(ctx, options)
  
}
```

```js
function label_tooltip(item, data) {

    var index = item.index
    var name = data.labels[index]

    var value = data.datasets[0].data[index]

    var tooltip = ' ' + name + ' - ' + value

    return tooltip
}
```

```js
chart()

document.getElementById('chart-info').innerHTML = chart_data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + '<br>TOTAL'
```

Comment: It seems like your fiddle is broken, The text is not in the middle of the doughnut and the doughnut is verry small

Comment: Oh. That's because of `responsive: true` - Forgot to update it on StackOverflow. Should be OK now. It is better to use fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/7ev2tnsb/

Answer (score 0):

For a custom tooltip you will need to put `enabled: false` in your tooltips option. I made a quick example that showcases what you want. It shows the custom tooltip after 1 sec by delaying the making of the table. If you go off the element it will remove it imideatly.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/ks3wgvLp/12/

code:

```
var tttimer;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.custom = function(tooltip) {
            
        // Tooltip Element
            var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
            }
      
      
      clearTimeout(tttimer);
      tttimer = setTimeout(() => {
      
            // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltip.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
            } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
            }

            // Set Text
            if (tooltip.body) {
                var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
                var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);

                var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                    var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
                    var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                    style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                    style += '; border-width: 2px';
                    var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
                    innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            }

            var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
            var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

            // Display, position, and set styles for font
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
            tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
            tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize;
            tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
            tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
      }, 1000)
        };
```

Credits for clearing timer first to make it work go to one of the mainainers of Chart.js